# How to use sass global variables from other components in vite/vue3

Tags: vue.js, variables, sass, vuejs3, vite

I want to use and change global variables from other components, my files structure looks like this...

[image]

I have my variables in global.sass file, but I can't access variables in other components.

Answer (score 33):

You need to set [configuration](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#css-preprocessoroptions) file `vite.config.js` :

```
css: {
  preprocessorOptions: {
    scss: {
      additionalData: `@import "@/assets/global.scss";`
    }
  }
},
```

also for local fonts you can add another configuration there, set alias:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  }
},
```

and then use it something like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Opensans-Bold';
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Opensans-Bold'), url(@/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI if anyone comes across this looks like the link has moved https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#css-preprocessoroptions

Comment: @Nikola Pavicevic does the code you write in ```vite.config.js``` file and the ```@import``` that you used in that work similar to [@import](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) that **sass** docs mentioned? If yes, do you have any solution that works similar to [@use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) that is recommended by sass and also works globally?

Answer (score 10):

### A new sass module system

Note: The Sass team discourages the continued use of the @import rule. Sass
will gradually phase it out over the next few years, and eventually remove it from the language entirely. Prefer the @use rule instead. (Note that only Dart Sass currently supports @use. Users of other implementations must use the @import rule instead.)

More details: [Here](https://sass-lang.com/blog/the-module-system-is-launched)

Below is the best way to global scss at that time.

#### vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@use "~/styles/_main.scss" as *;`,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
});
```

#### styles/abstracts/_colors.scss

```
$default: #000000;
$default-light: #333333;
$default-dark: #000000;
```

#### styles/abstracts/index.scss

```
@forward './colors';
@forward ...
```

#### styles/_main.scss

```
@forward './abstracts';
@forward './components';
@forward './layouts';
```

#### src/index.scss => don't forget to add this `import "./index.scss"` in `App.vue`

```
@forward './styles/abstracts';
@use './styles/abstracts' as *;

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: $font-primary;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-rendering: optimizespeed;
  color: $text;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}
```